# Fit image to canvas by width and fit canvas to image new height

Tags: html, canvas

How to fit image that bigger that canvas width to canvas(with scale) and then to fit canvas to image height after fit by width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
// Create a variable for the canvas and it's context
var canvas = document.getElementById("imageCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Initialise an image object
var image = new Image();

// When it loads an image
image.onload = function() {
  // Get the canvas' current style
  var canvasStyle = getComputedStyle(canvas);
  
  // Get it's current width, minus the px at the end
  var canvasWidth = canvasStyle.width.replace("px", "");
  
  // Work out the images ratio
  var imageRatio = this.width/this.height;
  
  // Work out the new height of the canvas, keeping in ratio with the image
  var canvasHeight = canvasWidth/imageRatio;
  
  // Set the canvas' height in the style tag to be correct
  canvas.style.height = canvasHeight+"px";
  
  // Set the width/height attributes to be correct (as this is what drawImage uses)
  canvas.width = canvasWidth;
  canvas.height = canvasHeight;
  
  // Draw the image at the right width/height
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
};

// Load an image
image.src="https://placekitten.com/g/600/800";
```

```css
#imageCanvas
{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="imageCanvas" width="400px" height="400px"></canvas>
```

There you go, shrinks the image to the right width, resizes canvas to the right height. Hopefully the comments explain everything.